# React js hide components on landing page

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I am new to react js, I am building the application. I have three components Landing page component, a status component, and an employee component. Whenever the Landing page load at the bottom of the landing page, it also loads the status component. I want to display the status component only when the employee component is loaded inside. How I can hide or maintain the component display.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Landing from "./views/Landing";
import status from "./views/status";
import employee from "./views/employee";
import Navigation from "./views/navbar";

function App() {
 <Router>
   <div className="App">
      <Navigation></Navigation>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Landing} />
           <Status></Status>  // when i click employee navbar this component is displaying            
           <Route path="/employee" component={employee}></Route> // this component does not appear     
         </Switch> 
   
   </div>
 </Router>
}
```

Comment: use one <Switch> and add all <Route> in there

Comment: `<Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Landing} />
        <Route path="/employee" component={employee} />
</Switch>`

Comment: or you can share your code anywhere sandbox or any other platform to get check what issues are you facing

Comment: I have updated the code, I followed the above mention using one switch, but when i click  on employee it will display only the ``` status component``` and not appearing ```employment component```

Comment: use `exact` prop to all `Route` component

Comment: its working !!!, thank you so much